# Casting Error In Powershell(System.Int32)

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a problem.

Firstly, There is a MSSQL Database and I sent to query with using PowerShell code. Then I take numbers from these tables (like U056258). After that, I want to mail the people have these numbers. But Powershell sends me an error. Like;

```
**Cannot convert value "U056258" to type "System.INT32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."**

**+CategoryInfo         :InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException**

**+FullyQualifiedErorId :InvalidCastFromStringToInteger**
```

Comment: Why do you even need `int` here? Email does not care. In fact, email body expects a string anyway. If you want an `int`, then just do something to remove the alpha character first `[int]"U3456".Substring(1)`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Actually, I do not want to int. I want to String but PowerShell ISE detect int for the variables. After little brainstorming, I solved the problem. The solution; `[String]$TheIdentity = $person.Description`

Answer (score 0):

What is the "U" at the beginning ? Is it an unsigned number ? Remove it.

Ah, your ID isalphanumeric. Guy, don't cast into int32. Or remove the "U" before.

Comment: Unfortunately, the identity have to start with the letter U. No It is not unsigned number. Actually the identity is the identity number of school.

Comment: 'U' have to be in Identity Numbers, I solved the problem; `[String]PersonIdentity = $Identity.Description`